# how to save fragments data to show to next login

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-sqlite

i have this application

[image: Image 1]

when user press at day on the calendar adds a new fragment with a tag of this date. He put data on fragments and show it in a linear layout like that [image: image 1]. Can I save fragments in my sqlidatabase with contentProvider and contentResolve so when user login again to have this data in the linear layout? Or I have to try something else?

I try to save the Fragments with Gson.

1) I got the fragments from manager to a List.
 2)Save the List with gson as json in a string variable
    and 
 3)get the fragments with type-typeToken

```
 @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(TAG,"onPause");
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("FragmentsList",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
    manager=getFragmentManager();
    fragmentList = manager.getFragments();
    if (fragmentList!=null) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(fragmentList); // error here cant serialize context
        editor.putString("ListFragment", json);
    }
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("FragmentsList",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String jsonreader=sharedPreferences.getString("ListFragment",null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<Fragment>>(){}.getType();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    manager=getFragmentManager();
    fragmentList=gson.fromJson(jsonreader,type);
    if (fragmentList!=null) {
        for (Fragment fragment : fragmentList) {
            manager.putFragment(bundle, "BundleFragment", fragment);
        }
    }
}
```

With this code, I got an error when I try to save the list with gson.tojson because I think fragments have context and can't get the format to json

Comment: you should not be saving the fragments, you should be saving the data associated with a day

Comment: how can i save the data for specific fragments in database?

Comment: but if the app get killed and user go to login and i do manager.findFragmentByTag(tag) howl the manager is gone to find fragment ? manager gona get reset and will not have fragment in history or not ? am i wrong ?

Comment: you need to save it in a database, shared preferences, a file, etc. something which does not get cleared

Comment: so you tell me to save the manager in database or in shared preferences ?

Comment: no. save something which allows you to know whether or not to make a fragment for a specific day, not the manager.

Comment: Wait I did that I check when to make fragment for a specific day by check if the tag exist in manager. if exist i hide previous fragment and add new one if not i show the fragment. The problem I want to have the data of  all fragments when user kill the app and come again and login. Seriously i dont understand what you tell me to do. I am noob at android so be a little specific. I can post my code when i add show and hide the fragments if you want